# How to do sum of alias column that is already sum in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, alias

I have mysql query that is.

```
select d.department_id,d.department_name,sum(e.salary) AS amount
from department d inner join employee e on d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id,d.department_name
```

I get grand total by using  this query .

```
select d.department_id,d.department_name,sum(e.salary) AS amount
from department d inner join employee e on d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id,d.department_name WITH ROLLUP
```

But I want this grand total by sum amount column alias like this

```
select d.department_id,d.department_name,sum(e.salary) AS amount, sum(SELECT(amount)) AS grand_total
from department d inner join employee e on d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id,d.department_name
```

My database structure is .

[image]

And my tables are

[image]

But I want like this .

[image]

Please Help me any one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an additional column use a `join` or subquery:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, sum(e.salary) AS amount,
       tot.salary
from department d inner join
     employee e
     on d.department_id = e.department_id inner join
     (select sum(e.salary) as salary from employee) tot
group by d.department_id, d.department_name, tot.salary;
```

Note:  this assumes that the total from the employee table is the total you want.    This seems like a reasonable assumption, but it might not be accurate if some employees do not have departments or if some employees are in multiple departments.  In that case, you just need to repeat the `join` to `department` in the subquery.